# How to apply the transistion animation equation on view in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

If I have transition equation like this:

```
 c*t/d + b
```

as used in the following function:

```
 public static float easeNone (float t,float b , float c, float d) {
                return c*t/d + b;
 }
```

how to apply this function for a view in android ? where:

```
t: current time
b: start value
c: change in value
d: duration
```

Something like in [this link](http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/#c3) . What  want to do is to move view (i.e. button) in some animation as in the link above , where the animation math equation is given

Comment: interpolator for animation?

Comment: @blackbelt sorry I don't understand you

Comment: what is the question? what does "how to apply this function for a view" mean? What does "transistion" mean ? Please try to improve your question

Comment: @blackbelt check the edit, could you get my question now ?

Comment: then as I told you need an interpolator for the animation

Comment: @blackbelt yes, sorry for misunderstand you

Comment: so just look how to create a custom interpolator. It should not be difficult

Comment: @blackbelt thank you dear. I have an answer below

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[Android Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)**

At the onTick method do this

```
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          long time = totaltime - millisUntilFinished;
          float x = easeNone(time, your parameters);
      }
```